# Defining a controller with $routeProvider using a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I'm trying the following code, but with no success:

```
MyApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $provide) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/'
    })


    .when('/:page', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page +'.html';
        },

    })
    .when('/:page/:child*', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page + '/' + $routeParams.child + '.html';
        },
        controller: function($routeParams) {
            return  $routeParams.child + '.' +  $routeParams.page + 'Controller';
         },
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

what i want to accomplish is to define the controller for each view with a function based on the $routParams variable:

```
controller: function($routeParams) {
            return  $routeParams.child + '.' +  $routeParams.page + 'Controller';
         },
```

while it works pretty good with the templateUrl, it doesn't seem to work when i define the controller.

Comment: I'm probably just missing something, but isn't `.when('/', { redirectTo: '/' })` kind of weird to do? Won't that result in a loop?

Comment: I don't know, it works for me, (even i realized i can remove it, since i declared the otherwise)

Comment: when you function in controller it creates a new controller and get assigned to that template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for achieving this would be, create a constant variable that would be assigned to `controller` inside that we want to load conditionally, we want set controller name by watching `$routeParams`, for that we could watch for `$routeChangeStart` and accordingly we will set `costants.controllerName` value, which would be the name of controller.

You could achieve this by something doing like below.

**Constant**

```
MyApp.constant('constants',{
  controllerName : ''
});
```

**Config**

```
MyApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide','constants', function($routeProvider, $provide, constants) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      redirectTo: '/'
    })
    .when('/:page', {
      templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
        return 'views/' + $routeParams.page + '.html';
      }
    })
    .when('/:page/:child*', {
      templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
        return 'views/' + $routeParams.page + '/' + $routeParams.child + '.html';
      },
      controller: constants.controllerName
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

**Run Block**

```
MyApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'constants', '$routeParams',
  function($rootScope, $location, constants, $routeParams) {
    // register listener to watch route changes
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        constants.controllerName = $routeParams.child + '.' + $routeParams.page + 'Controller'; //set controller name on $routeChangeStart
    });
}]);
```

I haven't tried this, I believe this code should work, Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help. but it doesn't work. the $routParams are not defined then.

Comment: i'm not getting any errors, i just see the controller doesn't work, because it doesn't provide the data it supposed to provide.   when i tried to put a 'debugger' inside the function, and put in the console :         $routeParams.child + '.' + $routeParams.page + 'Controller'      i got:       undefined.undefinedController

Comment: also do change event inside run block to `$routeChangeSuccess` inspite of `$routeChangeStart`